# WPF: How to bind a Visibility property to an xaml element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, viewmodel

I've got some problem I need some help with. I want to bind the visibility properties from a view model to the xaml elements so I get some visually changes (collapse or show in this case) by just changing the value in the viewmodel.

I got this xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PampelMuse.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:welcome="clr-namespace:PampelMuse.Views.Welcome"
    xmlns:backend="clr-namespace:PampelMuse.Views.Backend"
    xmlns:pampelMuse="clr-namespace:PampelMuse" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PampelMuse" Height="670" Width="864">
<Grid>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="Resources/Images/Backgrounds/4.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    <welcome:WelcomeScreen x:Name="UIWelcome" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UiWelcomeVisibility}" />
    <backend:BackendUI x:Name="UIBackend" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UiBackendVisibility}" />
</Grid>
```

The visibilities as you can see are binded to the properties **UiWelcomeVisibility** and **UiBackendVisibility** in the UIModel. These properties are now defined as followed:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ViewModel.ViewModel ViewModel = PampelMuse.ViewModel.ViewModel.GetInstance();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = ViewModel; // Setting the data context what effects all the xaml elements in this component too, including UIWelcome and BackendUI

        ViewModel.UIModel.UiBackendVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private static ViewModel instance = new ViewModel();
    public UIModel UIModel = UIModel.GetInstance();

    public static ViewModel GetInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And the UIModel:

```
public class UIModel
{
    private static UIModel instance = new UIModel();

    public Visibility UiWelcomeVisibility { get; set; }
    public Visibility UiBackendVisibility { get; set; }

    public static UIModel GetInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I just don't see any coding mistakes here (and I don't get some at runtime in fact) but the BackendUI-visibility-property is not changed by the UiBackendVisibility of UIModel.

Any ideas? Thanks so far.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the binding wrong. `Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UiWelcomeVisibility}"` sets the visibility of an element equal to *another visual element* named "UiWelcomeVisibility". There are two problems with this:

1. There is no element named "UiWelcomeVisibility" in the first place.
2. Even if there were, a visual element itself is not a valid value for the `Visibility` property.

What you want is to databind to the viewmodel instead. Assuming that you have already set the `DataContext` to the viewmodel, just use

```
<welcome:WelcomeScreen ... Visibility="{Binding UiWelcomeVisibility}" />
```

Comment: Good answer. Can you add the fact that this is shorthand for `Path=UiWelcomeVisibility`?

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately when I change the Bindung as you proposed it says "cannot resolve symbol UiWelcomeVisibility due to unknown data context" although the data context was set in constructor and I know that VS compiles the constructor while code checking.

Comment: @plain: The *designer* says that (kind of an important detail to mention), and it's logical because when you are designing your code is of course not running, so there's noone to set the data context. It should work fine at runtime.

Comment: @Jon: Okay, so there a no runtime errors just the, let me say, notice that the data context cannot be found at this time. But unfortunately it doesn't collapse the BackendUI at runtime although I made it now like `<backend:BackendUI x:Name="UIBackend" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding Path=UiBackendVisibility}" />` Did I forgot something else maybe? Actually, the bindings in fact should work with your changes.

Comment: @plain: Did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the viewmodel?

Comment: @Jon Aw, you got me! ^^ Thanks a lot, man, you saved my day. :)